# Search capabilities with Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-drive-api, google-cloud-storage

I'm going to use Google's infrastructure to store files and I hesitate between Google Drive and Google Cloud Storage. I don't think I'll store a lot of data (less than 50GB). However I would like to offer search functionality through files contents (FULL TEXT) to my users.
I know it's available with Google Drive SDK https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters but I'm not sure it is for Google Cloud Storage files ? I don't want to force my users to have a google account and they will be able to share files to others, and they will do all their stuff through my web site.

One more question, is there a way to manage identities with a Google API (create/update users) ? without a gmail account ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud storage does not offer full text search at this time.

Identities require a Google/gmail account, but check out signed URLs: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs.

Your app can determine whether one of your users should have access to an app and then hand the user a signed url that grants access to that object for a limited period of time.

Comment: Ok you're confirming that GCS does not support FULL TEXT :( Thanks for the idea of signed URLs but as I want to provide FULL TEXT support I think I'll go with Google Drive storage. Is there a way to provide an access to an item with a custom URL or an URL without drive.google.com ? I could use an app engine URL to construct a bridge but it may be a performance killer ...

Comment: I am pretty sure that you cannot do that with Google drive, but I don't really know enough about that API to answer authoritatively. Maybe try directing your question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-drive